# Set Line Chart Markers Colour Based on Conditional

Tags: javascript, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm trying to figure out how to set the markers to be a certain colour depending on what the value of the point is. So for example, if a point has a value between 0.1 and 1, I want the marker colour to be red.

This is how I'm initializing my chart:

```
this.chart = Anychart.line()                 
let dataSet = Anychart.data.set(this.graphData.data)               
let mapping = dataSet.mapAs({x: "day", value: "risk"})             
this.series = this.chart.line(mapping)
```

How do I apply individual marker styles to points that belong to the same series?

Mockup of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series markers don't support conditional filling via the function. There are two available solutions:

1. Create additional marker series. It supports conditional coloring via a function, for details check [the live sample](https://playground.anychart.com/tWHpiFnl).
2. Use line series markers, but apply individual marker setting in the data. This approach is demonstrated in [the live sample](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/BCT_General_Settings_03).